# Does the life cleric's Disciple of Life apply to revivify?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric

I have just helped a fellow 5e player set up their life domain cleric. However, we are both unsure whether the Disciple of Life feature should apply to them casting *revivify*, which they are able to cast as the party is level 9.

The DM is unavailable at the moment so I thought I’d ask the question to the greater world.

Comment: Hello and welcome! If you have time take the [tour] to find out more about our site. I have made an edit to your question in an attempt to improve readability. If you don't like it or I have changed the intent of your question feel free to revert my edit.

Answer (score 34):

### Yes it should apply

The life domain cleric disciple of life states (emphasis mine):

> whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher **to restore hit points to a creature**, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell's level.

And the Revivify spell states that:

> That creature returns to life with 1 hit point

A dead creature has no hit points. Revivify causes the creature to now have 1 hit point. This certainly qualifies as "restoring hit points".

So reviving a character with a 3rd level Revivify would start them with 6 hit points: 1 from revivify and 5 from disciple of life (flat 2 plus 3 from the level of the spell slot that was used).

See also [this related tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/533682928384217088) by Jeremy Crawford where it is implied that revivify does count as regaining hp:

> **Kari Suvivaara** @suvivaara · [Nov 15, 2014](https://mobile.twitter.com/suvivaara/status/533649670501720065)
>   @JeremyECrawford What happens upon casting Revivify spell to a creature killed by Chill Touch while CT hand is still clinging to the target?
>
> **Jeremy Crawford** @JeremyECrawford · [Nov 15, 2014](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/533682928384217088)
>   @suvivaara Cool spell interaction! The most straightforward reading is that revivify restores the target to life with 0 hit points.